# Time Complexity - Copying Map Entries to Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, hashmap, time-complexity

I was looking for efficient ways to sort a hashmap by it's value and I came across solutions that claim to be O(n log n) by copying the entries to a List and sorting the List by values; copy back into a LinkedHashMap. I was thinking this may be O(n^2) instead of O(n log n).

`List<Entry<K, V>> entries = new ArrayList<Entry<K, V>>(map.entrySet());`

I would like to confirm if the time complexity of the code above is O(n^2)?

This is my understanding: we iterate via the entries of the map (this is O(n)), and when we add each entry to a list, it gets added to the end of the list and the time required to do this would be O(n) as well making it O(n^2).

Is this correct?

Comment: "it gets added to the end of the list and the time required to do this would be O(n)" - Because it's being added to the end of the list, it's an amortized `O(1)`. The only thing that increases complexity is resizing the array, but that won't occur if you use the constructor that accepts a `Collection` (which you are).

Answer (score 3):

1. Performing `new ArrayList<Entry<K, V>>(map.entrySet())` is O(n). `map.entrySet()` will be converted to `Entry[]` with `toArray()`. There is no usual append and resize like with usual `add()`.
2. Sorting an `ArrayList` is O(n log n) due to [TimSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort).
3. Creating a `new LinedHashMap` from `ArrayList` is O(n).

The entire approach will be O(n log n) because sorting will be the dominant operation.

Comment: You have a typo, it's TimSort :)